# What is wrong with my set state on a React.JS component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React.js component that is meant to display chat messages. I am using signalR and that works fine. I am able to connect and get messages. I set some initial state on my component based on dummy message data. But in my event handler for new messages:

Which is specified inside my `componentDidMount()` event in my component.  I am unable to add the message to my component state.   Here is the applicable portion of the code.

```
        connection.on('newMessage', function (message) {
            alert(message.sender);
            this.setState({
                messages: [...this.state.messages, { messageID: 77777, sender: 'user2', text: 'text2' }]
            })

        });
```

I know it fires since I get the alert and the message I sent via SignalR is formatted correctly. 
You can see that I actually hardcode the message data rather than trying to use the actual message data because I wanted to rule out any message format issue:

`messages: [...this.state.messages, { messageID: 77777, sender: 'user2', text: 'text2' }]`

Would actually be:

`messages: [...this.state.messages, message]`

But I hardcode for now to rule out factors.

Very similar set state code works when setting up my component with dummy data, but there is something about the way it is accessing state from within my even handler or something that I always get the following error in the console debugger:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
```

Below I include my entire ReactChatUI.js file contents, so you can see that the message hanlder for signalR is an inline function.  I Would like to have this be function outside of the component, but I figured this was the easiest way to get access to the state.

```
'use strict';

const apiBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:7071';

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(`${apiBaseUrl}/api`)
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();


console.log('connecting...');
connection.start()
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('connection established', response);
        createMessage(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9), 'User', 'User message');
    })
    .catch(logError);




function logError(err) {
    console.error('Error establishing connection', err);
}




class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            messages: [{ messageID: 1111, sender: 'olduser', text: 'old message' }]
        }
    }




    componentDidMount() {


        this.setState({
            messages: [...this.state.messages,
                { messageID: 2222, sender: 'user1', text: 'text1' },
                { messageID: 6666, sender: 'user2', text: 'text2' }
            ]

        })

        connection.on('newMessage', function (message) {
            alert(message.sender);
            this.setState({
                messages: [...this.state.messages, { messageID: 77777, sender: 'user2', text: 'text2' }]
            })

        });


    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <MessageList messages={this.state.messages} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function createMessage(msgID, sender, messageText) {

    return axios.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/api/messages`, {
        messageID: msgID,
        sender: sender,
        text: messageText
    }).then(resp => {
        console.log('message sent', messageText);
    });
}


class MessageList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <ul className="message-list">
                {this.props.messages.map((message, index) => {
                    return (
                        // <li key={message.id} className="message">
                        //  <div>{message.message}</div>
                        <li key={message.messageID} className="message">
                            <div>{message.sender}</div>
                            <div>{message.text}</div>
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is the HTML file which hosts it (ReactChatUI.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ReactChatUI.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@aspnet/signalr@1.1.2/dist/browser/signalr.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js" crossorigin></script>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script src="ReactChatUI.js" type="text/babel">
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code won't work because "newMessage" needs an arrow function to reference `this` correctly. Change `connection.on('newMessage', function (message) {` to `connection.on('newMessage', (message) => {`

Comment: yeah `this` refers to the callback function

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a regular function, `this` is getting bound to the context of the function not the class. A way to solve this is convert it to an arrow function.

```html
 connection.on('newMessage', (message) => {
            alert(message.sender);
            this.setState({
                messages: [...this.state.messages, { messageID: 77777, sender: 'user2', text: 'text2' }]
            })

        });
```

Refer to this [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256) for more information on the difference.

Comment: this doesn't appear to be the case. Same either way.